# Public Embedded Google Maps Engine Map Forces Users to Log in

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, safari, google-maps-engine, google-maps-engine-lite

I have created a map using Google's Map Engine. I have set the permissions to "Public on the web - Anyone on the Internet can find and view". It even explicitly says "Access:Anyone (no sign-in required)". I have copied and pasted the iframe html code into my website to embed the map. This works fine when I am logged in, but I cannot view the map when I am not logged in (it just doesn't show up on my website and when I try to go to the url directly, it forces me to log in). I have not tested extensively, but this seems to only be a problem in Safari and Internet Explorer--the map shows up in Firefox and Chrome even when I am not logged in.

FWIW, the url of the embedded map is: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/embed?mid=zKb6YkxKtQGA.kQRHsaBqmIiw

If anyone has found a work around for this while still using the Maps Engine, please let me know. If I must, I will resort to using the Google Maps API if that will solve the problem, but in the interest of time I would prefer to use the Google Maps Engine.

Comment: I see the embedded map in IE

Comment: And you're not logged in to your Google account?

Comment: No, I'm not logged in: http://i.imgur.com/czZZ5V1.jpg?1 ("Anmelden" is german for "log in")

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It seems to only happen in a browser that has never logged in to any Google service. As soon as I log in for the first time, I can then log out and the map will still render.